# Isomorphism between fundamental groups by attaching $n$-cell

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $x_0\in X$. I want to prove the following let $f:S^{n-1}\to X$ be a continuous map. Then, $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(X\cup_f D^n,x_0)$ for $n\geq 3$.

I want to use van Kampen's theorem, so I choose $U=X\setminus\{\text{centre of $D^n$\}}$, $V=int(D^n)$. Then, $U\cup V=X\cup_f D^n$ and $U\cap V=int(D^n)\setminus\{\text{Centre of $D^n$}\}$. Intuitively I think this would work. But on page 50 of Hatcher, an alternative, and in my opninion more difficult prove is given. Is my proof wrong in some sense, since Hathcer does it more extensive?

Comment: How would you calculate the fundamental group of $U$?

Comment: Doesn't $U$ deformation retract on $X$?

Comment: Indeed it is. But note that Hatcher shows something stronger: not only that these groups are isomorphic. But also that the isomorphism is induced by inclusion $X\hookrightarrow X\cup_f D^n$.

Comment: I see, but my proof doesn't break down, does it???

Comment: Looks correct, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hatcher attaches $2$-cells, but you attach an $n$-cell for $n \ge 3$. If you attach a $2$-cell, then $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is in general not isomorphic to $\pi_1(X\cup_f D^n,x_0)$. As an example take $X = S^1$ and $f = id : S^1 \to S^1$. More precisely, Hatcher proves that $i : X \hookrightarrow Y$ induces a surjection $i_*$ on fundamental groups and determines its kernel.

So what is the difference if you have $n \ge 3$?

Independent of $n$ you argue correctly that you can apply the Seifert van Kampen theorem. You have $\pi_1(U) = \pi_1(X), \pi_1(V) = 0$. But now you have $U \cap V \simeq S^{n-1}$ whence $\pi_1(U \cap V) = 0$ for $n \ge 3$ and $\pi_1(U \cap V) = \mathbb{Z}$ for $n = 2$. This implies that $i_*$ is an ísomorphism for $n \ge 3$. This conclusion is wrong für $n = 2$.

Comment: I don't see how van Kampen implies that $i_*$ is an isomorphism. To me it only shows that these groups are isomorphic, not necessarily via $i_*$. And I think that's the main reason Hatcher is more complicated.

Comment: @freakish Since $X$ is a strong deformatioin retract of $U$, this is equivalent to $j_*$ being an isomorphism, where $j : U \hookrightarrow Y$. Seifert van Kampen says that the square formed by the inclusions $i_1: U \cap V \to U, i_2: U \cap V \to V, j: U  \to Y, k : V \to Y$ produces a pushout diagram when $\pi_1$ is applied. But $(i_2)_*$ is an isomorphism, hence also $j_*$ is one.

Comment: How do I know that $U$ and $V$ are open in the topology on $X\cup_f D^n$?

Comment: You have $U = X \cup_f D^n \setminus \{ \text{centre of }  D^n \}$ (note the typo in your question) which is open because the removed one-point set is closed. Morever $int(D^n) =  X \cup_f D^n  \setminus X$ is open because $X$ is closed in the adjunction space.

Comment: In general, $X$ does not need to be path-connected, so neither $U$. How can I fix this, using path components?

Comment: Let $X'$ be the path component of $x_0$ in $X$. Then $\pi_1(X,x_0) = \pi_1(X',x_0)$. Now either $f(S^{n-1}) \subset X'$ so that $\pi_1(X \cup_f D^n, x_0) = \pi_1(X' \cup_f D^n, x_0)$ and Seifert van Kampen applies for $X'$ or  $f(S^{n-1}) \cap X' = \emptyset$ so that we see directly $\pi_1(X \cup_f D^n, x_0) = \pi_1(X', x_0)$.